# Remove vertical line on labels in flotcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I would like remove the vertical line on the far right labels and move them closer to the first right label. my wish is attached as a screenshot, also coloring the specific labels would be great.

[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi8Es.png)

[desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1nMG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `color` option for each axis to make it invisible (fully transparent color or set to the background color) and the `font` option to define a different color for the tick labels. For example:

```
var options = {
    //...
    axes: [{
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0),
        font: {
            color: 'orange'
        }
    }, {
        // axis 2 ...
    }],
    //...
};
```

For more details see the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes).

Comment: Good to know, you should accept the answer then, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).